# problemas con getPropertyName();

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente parte del código:

```
public class ControlaEstat implements VetoableChangeListener{

    private String [] valors = {"A punt","Avariat","Ocupat"}; // estats permesos

    /**
     * Llenca una excepcio si el canvi demanat vol assignar com estat un valor
     * diferent dels anteriors ('A punt', 'Avariat' o 'Ocupat')
     * @param evt esdeveniment amb informacio sobre el canvi que es demana
     * @throws PropertyVetoException excepcio que indica que el nou valor no es correcte
     */

    @Override
    public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) throws PropertyVetoException {
       //  TODO cal implementar el metode
        String nouValor=evt.getPropertyName();


      if(!nouValor.equalsIgnoreCase(valors.toString())){
          throw new PropertyVetoException("Incorrecte", evt);
      }
      }
    }
```

Pero no me funciona y no se como hacerlo.
Es decir tengo que controlar que el texto que se pone en el panel sea uno de los valores si no es así entonces que salga el error throw new PropertyVetoException("Incorrecte", evt);

que puedo estar haciendo mal?

---

Añado la clase estat.

```
public class Estat {

// com es veu al codi dels metodes, s'han d'anomenar vcs i pcs 
    private final VetoableChangeSupport vcs = new VetoableChangeSupport(this);
    private final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);


    private String estat;

    /**
     * obte una cadena amb l'estat del servei
     * @return 
     */

    public String getEstat(){
        return estat;
    }

    /**
     * assigna una cadena a l'estat del servei
     * @param estat cadena a assignar com a nou estat
     * @throws PropertyVetoException en cas que l'estat no sigui correcte
     */
    public void setEstat(String estat) throws PropertyVetoException{
        String oldEstat=this.estat;
        vcs.fireVetoableChange("Estat.estat", oldEstat, estat);
        this.estat=estat;
        pcs.firePropertyChange("Estat.estat", oldEstat, estat);
    }


// Com es veu al codi de la classe Pantalla, s'han d'anomenar
// addPropertyChangeListener i addVetoableChangeListener
    public void addVetoableChangeListener(VetoableChangeListener listener){
      this.vcs.addVetoableChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener){
        this.pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

}
```

---

El error es que da igual lo que ponga que siempre me salta esto:

```
   private void jTextFieldNouEstatActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
        try {
            estat.setEstat(jTextFieldNouEstat.getText());
            jTextFieldEstatActual.setText(estat.getEstat());
            jTextFieldNouEstat.setText("");
            jTextAreaHistoric.setText(enregistra.toString());
            jTextAreaHistoric.setRows(jTextAreaHistoric.getRows()+1);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Nou estat erroni", "Avis", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa "no me funciona"? ¿Se está invocando el listener? ¿Se está añadiendo a la lista de listeners?

Comment: no me funciona es que por mucho que ponga los valores me da error como sino existieran

Comment: Hola @MontseMkd , añade el error que te esté dando.

Comment: es decir no es un error lo que me dice el programa es que el el valor no esta dentro de "valors". es decir llama a   throw new PropertyVetoException("Incorrecte", evt); siempre da igual lo que ponga.

Comment: Por eso pensaba que el error estaba en mi forma de hacer la llamada.. pero quizás esta dentro de estat.

Comment: probablemente el valor `String nouValor=evt.getPropertyName();` no sea el correcto, sino como sea que se llame el 3er parametro en `vcs.fireVetoableChange("Estat.estat", oldEstat, estat);`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de una forma muy simple:

```
public class ControlaEstat implements VetoableChangeListener{

    private String [] valors = {"A punt","Avariat","Ocupat"}; // estats permesos

    /**
     * Llenca una excepcio si el canvi demanat vol assignar com estat un valor
     * diferent dels anteriors ('A punt', 'Avariat' o 'Ocupat')
     * @param evt esdeveniment amb informacio sobre el canvi que es demana
     * @throws PropertyVetoException excepcio que indica que el nou valor no es correcte
     */

    @Override
    public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) throws PropertyVetoException {
       //  TODO cal implementar el metode
        String nouValor=evt.getPropertyName();

        if(!Arrays.asList(valors).contains(nouValor)){
          throw new PropertyVetoException("Incorrecte", evt);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: tampoco me salta esta parte del código :

Comment: private void jTextFieldNouEstatActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
        try {
            estat.setEstat(jTextFieldNouEstat.getText());
            jTextFieldEstatActual.setText(estat.getEstat());
            jTextFieldNouEstat.setText("");
            jTextAreaHistoric.setText(enregistra.toString());

Comment: jTextAreaHistoric.setRows(jTextAreaHistoric.getRows()+1);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Nou estat erroni", "Avis", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }

Comment: @MontseMkd entonces el error está en otra parte, como te han comentado los compañeros.

Comment: ya me lo imagino, pero no se donde!! gracias!!

Comment: Pero a ver, ¿este método `jTextFieldNouEstatActionPerformed` a qué clase pertenece?, ¿para qué sirve? ... Comenta un poco sobre lo que hace tu App editando la pregunta, quizá podamos ayudarte, @MontseMkd

Comment: voy añadir todas las clases. un segundo!

Comment: Pero no añadas clases sin más, explica un poco lo que hace tu App en este punto del error, poniendo el código relevante, @MontseMkd

Comment: El programa es una pantalla con 3  cajas de texto. 

En la que introducimos el texto y luego analizamos lo que se ha introducido, si es de valores entonces registra sino salta ese mensaje de error. Voy a copiar las clases que creo que son fundamentales. ( Son cortas )

Comment: ya esta lo fundamental..

Comment: @MontseMkd tu comentario es de hace 32 minutos, y la última edición fue hace 45 minutos... Como la pregunta está planteada ahora es imposible comprender el contexto de tu aplicación y poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que recorrer el array, ya que sino estás comparando con todo el array (`"A punt", "Avariat","Ocupat"`):

```
public class ControlaEstat implements VetoableChangeListener{

    private String [] valors = {"A punt","Avariat","Ocupat"}; // estats permesos

    /**
     * Llenca una excepcio si el canvi demanat vol assignar com estat un valor
     * diferent dels anteriors ('A punt', 'Avariat' o 'Ocupat')
     * @param evt esdeveniment amb informacio sobre el canvi que es demana
     * @throws PropertyVetoException excepcio que indica que el nou valor no es correcte
     */

    @Override
    public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) throws PropertyVetoException {
       //  TODO cal implementar el metode
       String nouValor=evt.getPropertyName();

       for (String valor : valors) {
           if(!nouValor.equalsIgnoreCase(valor)){
               throw new PropertyVetoException("Incorrecte", evt);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seguramente el problema que le esté dando es ese, pero es recomendable que el usuario confirme cual es el problema que está teniendo, sino estamos dando respuestas "al azar", y para próximas consultas no será un "problema y una solución" sino que será una solución dada a un supuesto problema. No digo que tu respuesta este mal, digo que es preferible que confirme el que pregunta.

Comment: si imprimo un  System.out.println(valor+"  " +nouValor); justo después del if me dice esto: 
A punt  Estat.estat

Voy a poner lo que tengo en Estat.estat.

Si pongo A punt me sale el mismo error es decir que me salta el error.

Comment: Como hay tres estados diferentes, `nouValor` siempre va a ser diferente al menos a dos de ellos... Este código siempre lanzará la excepción.